# Curl request with params to Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I'm working on `Laravel 5.2` with `Guzzle 6.2`, and I have this CURL request :

```
curl -X POST "https://api.lifebot.fr/letters" \
  -u "test_12345678901234567890:" \
  -d '{
   "description": "Demo Letter 1",
   "to": {
    "name": "LIFEBOT",
    "address_line1": "30 rue de la république",
    "address_city": "Paris",
    "address_postalcode": "75015",
    "address_country": "France"
   },
   "color" : "color",
   "postage_type" : "prioritaire",
   "from": {
    "name": "LIFEBOT",
    "address_line1": "30 rue de la république",
    "address_city": "Paris",
    "address_postalcode": "75015",
    "address_country": "France"
   },
   "source_file": "<html style=\"padding-top: 3px; margin: 0.5px;\">Lettre HTML for {{name}}<\/html>",
   "source_file_type": "html",
   "variables" : {
    "name" : "Lifebot"
   }
}'
```

This request is OK if KI use a terminal for testing.

So, the params -u is my API key, and -d is datas to sent to the API.
How can I convert this with Guzzle ?

I tried something like :

```
$result = $client->request('GET',
          'https://api.lifebot.fr/', [
          'u' => 'test_12345678901234567890'
          ]);
```

Wha'ts the syntax with Guzzle for add my param -u and my param -d ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should keep making the same request type (e.g., `POST` instead of `GET`). Regarding curl `-u` param, this is the authentication param, so you can translate to guzzle to `auth` with username set to apiKey and null password. Curl `-d` param is just the body content sent in the post request. So I believe that it would be something like the following:

```
$client->request('POST', 
                 'https://api.lifebot.fr/', 
                 [ 
                     'auth' = [ 'test_12345678901234567890', '' ],
                     'body' =>      '{
                          "description": "Demo Letter 1",
                       ...
                        "name" : "Lifebot"
                       }
                    }'
                 ]);
```

Comment: Same as other answer, I get : Client error: `GET https://api.lifebot.fr/` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":{"message":"Missing authentication","status_code":401}}

Comment: Seems that you just need to change the order: `'auth' = ['test_12345678901234567890', '']`. The username comes first.

Comment: updating the answer according to Alexey feedback :)